# how do you git push only the new commit

Tags: git

> Because Git is distributed, and committers can commit within their own
>   repositories, they can make a series of commits, then git squash the
>   series of commits to make a new commit, then git push only the new
>   commit. In this case you don't have the original commits anywhere:
>   they are only in the committer's repository, not on GitHub and not in
>   your clone either.

How do you "git push only the new commit" ?

Answer (score 1):

It is just a normal push. I am pretty sure what they mean there: you push just the squashed commit - not the commits that existed before the squash.
Lets say you made commit 1/2/3 and squashed to 4 - then you push with a normal `git push` - then commit 4 is pushed and exists remote (e.g. on github) and 1/2/3 only exist locally